# Is it possible to use cloud-init and heat-cfntools inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, openstack, dockerfile, openstack-heat

I want to use OpenStack Heat to create an application which consists of several Docker containers, and monitor some metrics of these containers, like: CPU/Mem utilization, and other application-specific metrics.

So is it possible to install cloud-init and heat-cfntools when prepare the Docker image via Dockerfile, and then run a Docker container based on the image which has cloud-init and heat-cfntools running in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> So is it possible to install cloud-init and heat-cfntools when prepare the Docker image via Dockerfile

It is *possible* to use `cloud-init` inside a Docker container, if you (a) have an image with `cloud-init` installed, (b) have the correct commands configured in your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` script, and (c) your container is running in an environment with an available metadata service.

Of those requirements, (c) is probably the most problematic; unless you are booting containers using the `nova-docker` driver, is is unlikely that your containers will have access to the Nova metadata service.

I am not particularly familiar with `heat-cfntools`, although a quick glance at the code suggests that it *may* work without `cloud-init` by authenticating against the Heat CFN API using ec2-style credentials, which you would presumably need to provide via environment variables or something.

That said, it is typically much less necessary to run cloud-init inside Docker containers, the theory being that if you need to customize an image, you'll use a Dockerfile to build a new one based on that image and re-deploy, or specify any necessary additional configuration via environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. And actually besides customizing an image, I'd also like to monitor some application specific metrics (not CPU/Mem/etc) of a container, i.e., I may run an application in a container which can be used to process some tasks, I'd like to know how many tasks are being processed, and how many are pending. I want such metrics can be reported out so that I can scale up/down the application (create more container/delete some existing containers) based on such info.

Answer (score 0):

If your tools require monitoring processes on the host, you'll probably want to run with

```
docker run --pid=host
```

This is a feature introduced in Docker Engine version 1.5.

See http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#pid-settings